# Identify if text is contained with a column, then concatenate with column heading

Tags: r

I am collecting injury survey data on patients over time. The data asks each patient if they are sore on one or both sides, then asks for further detail, which is a text box input.

I now wish to 1) test if text exists for each patient, in every column then 2) if text does exist, concatenate the heading of the body area with the side before 3) finishing with the exact details in brackets, at the end of this concatenated text.

My database has over 500 obs on 70 variables. A (small) example of my data is:

```
head((RawData[,c(1,12:13)]), 5)
   Patient ID    Elbow                       Elbow Details
1  A             <NA>                             <NA>
2  B             <NA>                             <NA>
3  C             <NA>                             <NA>
4  D         Pain on One Side             Pain on my right
5  E             <NA>                             <NA>
```

My anticipated output would be:

```
  Patient ID    Elbow Soreness                      
    1  A             <NA>                             
    2  B             <NA>                             
    3  C             <NA>                             
    4  D         Elbow: Pain on One Side. (Pain on my right)                      
    5  E             <NA>
```

Is this possible within R? In Excel, I could simply use the text of the heading and write an IF statement to assess if text existed or not. If it did, I would then concatenate text in the next column. I wish to use R, given how big my database is and I use this for analysis, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr);
df %>%
    mutate(Elbow_soreness = ifelse(
        Elbow == "<NA>",
        NA,
        sprintf("Elbow: %s (%s)", Elbow, Elbow_Details))) %>%
    select(Patient_ID, Elbow_soreness);
#  Patient_ID                             Elbow_soreness
#1          A                                       <NA>
#2          B                                       <NA>
#3          C                                       <NA>
#4          D Elbow: Pain on One Side (Pain on my right)
#5          E                                       <NA>
```

Or in base R:

```
df$Elbow_soreness <- ifelse(
    df$Elbow == "<NA>",
    NA,
    sprintf("Elbow: %s (%s)", df$Elbow, df$Elbow_Details));
df[, c(1, 4)];
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Patient_ID    Elbow                       Elbow_Details
A             NA                             NA
B             NA                             NA
C             NA                             NA
D         'Pain on One Side'             'Pain on my right'
E             NA                             NA", header = T)
```

---

### Update

To address your comment and account for missing `Elbow_soreness` entries, you can use two nested `ifelse` conditions:

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Patient_ID    Elbow                       Elbow_Details
A             NA                             NA
B             NA                             NA
C             NA                             NA
D         'Pain on One Side'             'Pain on my right'
E         'Pain on One Side'                 NA
F             NA                             NA", header = T)


library(dplyr);
df %>%
    mutate(Elbow_soreness = ifelse(
        is.na(Elbow),
        NA,
        ifelse(
            is.na(Elbow_Details),
            sprintf("Elbow: %s", Elbow),
            sprintf("Elbow: %s (%s)", Elbow, Elbow_Details)))) %>%
    select(Patient_ID, Elbow_soreness);
#  Patient_ID                             Elbow_soreness
#1          A                                       <NA>
#2          B                                       <NA>
#3          C                                       <NA>
#4          D Elbow: Pain on One Side (Pain on my right)
#5          E                    Elbow: Pain on One Side
#6          F                                       <NA>
```

Comment: This is working great, my only issue is if there is no comment in "Elbow_Soreness" the NA is still printed in the "Elbow_Details" column. Considering the example above, if there was an NA under "Elbow_Details" for Patient ID=="D" then "Elbow_Soreness" would read as: Elbow: Pain on One Side. NA.

Comment: @user2716568 I've made some changes, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, that is a fantastic help. Thank you so very much!